# C compile error: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from struct to const struct

Tags: c

aes.h

```
struct aes_key_st {
    unsigned int rd_key[4 * (AES_MAXNR + 1)];
    int rounds;
};
typedef struct aes_key_st AES_KEY;
:
void AES_decrypt(const unsigned char *in, unsigned char *out,
                 const AES_KEY *key);
```

test.c

```
void test ()
{
  unsigned char in[16];
  unsigned char out[16];
  AES_KEY key;

  AES_encrypt(in, out, key);

}
```

The above code gave this compile error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'AES_encrypt'
      AES_encrypt(in, out, key);
      ^~~~~~~~~~~
note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'AES_KEY' (aka 'aes_key_st') to 'const AES_KEY *' (aka 'const aes_key_st *') for 3rd argument; take the address of the argument with &
```

So when I fixed this with (as suggested by the error message):

```
void test ()
{
  :
  AES_encrypt(in, out, &key);
}
```

It seems to have fixed the compile issue.

What was I doing wrong earlier ?

Comment: That looks like a C++ error message, not  C. Are you sure which language you are compiling for?

Comment: Why are you showing the `AES_decrypt()` signature (declaration) from the header when the other code is attempting to call `AES_encrypt()`?  It would be more sensible to show the `AES_encrypt()` declaration.

Comment: Note that the error message diagnoses what is wrong: `
note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'AES_KEY' (aka 'aes_key_st') to 'const AES_KEY *' (aka 'const aes_key_st *') for 3rd argument; take the address of the argument with &` — learn to read error messages!

Answer (score 2):

> What was I doing wrong earlier ?

You passed the contents of `key` instead of the address of `key` in memory.